# How to use the statsmodels robust regression predict function and output a prediction interval?

Tags: python-3.x, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to predict out of sample data with statsmodels robust linear regression. I am having
difficulties doing so with the predict function. Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.random.rand(500)
y = np.random.rand(500)

x_train = x[0:200]
x_test = x[200:]
y_train = y[0:200]
y_test = y[200:]

X = sm.add_constant(x_train)
model = sm.RLM(y_train, X, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())

predict = result.predict(x_test)
```

When I try to use the predict function I get the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,300) and (2,) not aligned: 300 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

When I try to reshape the x_test variable with the following code:

```
X_test = x_test.reshape(-1,2)
predict = resutl.predict(X_test)
```

It works but the predict variable array has only 150 predictions and I want the number of predictions to be 300 to be able to compare them with the y_test variable.

How can I use the predict function to give me same length of output as the y_test variable?
How can I print a prediction interval for each of the out of sample data?

Comment: you didn't `add_constant` to X_test. x_test needs to have the same number and kind of columns as x_train

Comment: Yes a constant was needed. Solved the issue of the error.